# Can't run tor browser through configured proxychains in linux

Tags: linux, networking, browser, proxy, tor

I recently configured my proxychains to soc5, and it is working fine but when I run the command `proxychains ./tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser` , tor starts but doesn't connect to internet. it just tries to connect to internet but can't.

But it works fine without using the proxychains.
help me please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please compare how you configured proxychains with [this article](https://itigic.com/use-proxychains-and-tor-on-linux-to-be-anonymous/). You might be missing some step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current Tor browser does everything necessary, what ProxyChains would do for normal programs using TCP connections, itself.  Because ProxyChains intercepts all libc network functions and replaces them by its own, the Tor browser fails to establish the connections it needs.